# Javascript Kendo Grid "Cannot read property 'length' of null" Error

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I have an expandable kendo grid that is returning data from two stored procedures grouped by different entities. However, it is only returning data in the payload column for one of the three entities. When debugging in the developer console, it returns "Cannot read property 'length' of null." I have commented the line of code that seems to be causing the error. I am unsure why it would only do this for one of three entity values, but was wondering if anyone had a suggestion to fix as I am a beginnger. Please just let me know, thanks!

```
function InitiateGrid(e) {        
        var grid = e.detailRow.find(".entityDetail").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                transport: {
                    read: function (option) {
                        $.ajax({
                            contentType: "json",
                            url: "/Test.svc/json/GetDetail",
                            success: function (result) {
                                option.success(result.Response); //error happening within this line of code
                            },
                            error: function (result) {
                                option.error(result.Response);
                            },
                            data: {
                                entityId: function () { return $("#txtEntityId").val(); },
                                entityTypeName: function () { return $("#txtEntityType").val(); }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            Number: { type: "string", editable: false, nullable: true },
                            Id: { type: "string", editable: false },
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
            scrollable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: false,
            selectable: "row",
            columns: [
                {
                    filterable: false,
                    title: "Number",
                    field: "Number",
                    width: 25,
                },
                {
                    filterable: false,
                    field: "Id",
                    title: "Id",
                    width: 25,
                }
            ]
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need another Ajax request inside [Kendo Data Source](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/overview#to-remote-service).

```
transport: {
   read: {
      url: "/Test.svc/json/GetDetail",
      type: "get",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
         entityId: function () { return $("#txtEntityId").val(); },
         entityTypeName: function () { return $("#txtEntityType").val(); }
      }
   },
```